# how to using check box with value from database where type coloumn in database (set) codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox

I have checkbox example hobby
first checkbox  : footbal
second checkbox  :  study
third checkbox :dance
.......

Ichoose first and second checkbox
and I want this checkbox inserting mycoloumn like this

hobby: (football,study)

how to implement with codeigniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this. When you add the `[]` to the name of an input with the same name, it will be saved as an array in your post:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby_1[]" value="football" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby_1[]" value="dancing" />
</div>
```

So your `$_POST['hobby_1'] || ($this->input->post('hobby_1')` would look like `Array(2) [ "football", "dancing" ]`, or be filled with whatever you have checked. *NOTE* this will now always be saved as an array, so even if there is only one checked, you will still have to access this as an array.

As far as saving, you would just loop through the inputs and either build an array and insert it at one time, or you would loop through and insert them individually.